# Mapnik/Tilemill: Align or orient a Marker along a Line, such as a Gate

Tags: tilemill, mapnik

In Mapnik (actually Tilemill), using OSM data, I'm trying to draw a gate across a way, such that the gate is perpendicular to the road.  But the gate always gets drawn with the same orientation, unless I manually rotate it to match a specific road.

I've been using a Marker, placed along a line, both svg, arrow and ellipse.

Is there some way when querying the barrier points from the database, that the orientation of the line can be pulled at the same time and stored as metadata with the point, so that it can be used to then perform a unique rotation for each point?